# Oracle Object types: why does changing an object attribute has no effect after asigning it to a parent object?

Tags: oracle, object-type

Lets say I have two Oracle Object Types: 
Employee and Manager (definitions below)

If I execute this code then employee -> manager.name is "Johnson":

```
DECLARE
  employee EMPLOYEE_OT;
  manager MANAGER_OT;
BEGIN
  employee := EMPLOYEE_OT(123, 'Robinson');
  manager := MANAGER_OT(321, 'Peeters');

  manager.name := 'Johnson';    -- <=== first rename
  employee.manager := manager;  -- <=== then assign

END;
```

==> employee.manager.name = "Johnson"

But if I first assign manager to employee before changing the name then employee -> manager.name remains "Peeters":

```
DECLARE
  employee EMPLOYEE_OT;
  manager MANAGER_OT;
BEGIN
  employee := EMPLOYEE_OT(123, 'Robinson');
  manager := MANAGER_OT(321, 'Peeters');

  employee.manager := manager;  -- <=== first assign
  manager.name := 'Johnson';    -- <=== then rename

END;
```

==> employee.manager.name = "Peeters"

How can I fix this?

Definitions:

Employee:

```
create or replace TYPE EMPLOYEE_OT FORCE
AS OBJECT (
     id NUMBER
,    name VARCHAR2 (256 CHAR)
,    manager MANAGER_OT

,    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION EMPLOYEE_OT (
         p_id NUMBER
       , p_name VARCHAR2
       , p_manager MANAGER_OT
     ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);

create or replace TYPE BODY EMPLOYEE_OT AS

  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION EMPLOYEE_OT (
            p_id NUMBER
       ,    p_name VARCHAR2
       ,    p_manager MANAGER_OT
      )
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  AS
  BEGIN
    SELF.id := p_id;
    SELF.name := p_name;
    SELF.manager := p_manager;
    RETURN;
  END;
end;
/
```

Manager:

```
create or replace TYPE MANAGER_OT FORCE
AS OBJECT (
     id NUMBER
,    name VARCHAR2 (256 CHAR)

,    CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION MANAGER_OT (
         p_id NUMBER
       , p_name VARCHAR2
     ) RETURN SELF AS RESULT
);

create or replace TYPE BODY MANAGER_OT AS

  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION MANAGER_OT (
            p_id NUMBER
       ,    p_name VARCHAR2
      )
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
  AS
  BEGIN
    SELF.id := p_id;
    SELF.name := p_name;
    RETURN;
  END;
end;
/
```

Comment: i would guess that oracle doesn't work with references, but with values. When passing the parameters, you can explicitly tell oracle by using `NOCOPY`that it should be pass  by reference.

Comment: I thought that IN parameters were By Reference by default: https://oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plsql/cache/nocopy-directive.html: "IN parameters are always passed by reference."

Comment: I can imagine that it's a kind of security mechanism.
You cannot change an in parameter within a procedure, for this reason it is actually ok if the value is passed as a reference. it also reduce unnecessary CPU cycles and memory consumption. Values instead of references by out parameters it might be a kind of  default "security mechanism".

Comment: This is not really the issue, I am not trying to modify the object inside a function. Please see my question.

Comment: The problem is that the manager object is assigned as a value and not as a reference.  if you want to change the values in the already assigned object, you have to access them explicitly. at least that's what it looks like.

Comment: indeed, though this is so strange if you are used to work with OO languages...